# How do I flatten JSON nested objects while retaining the internal {} in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

This is the original response from the API.

```
 {
  result: [
    {
      activeFrom: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
      activeTo: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
      distance: 0,
      duration: '00:00:00',
      rule: [Object],
      device: [Object],
      diagnostic: [Object],
      driver: 'UnknownDriverId',
      version: '00000000000061b9',
      id: 'a30M9pPNZSEq7DgUdYrF8xw'
    },
    {
      activeFrom: '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
      activeTo: '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
      distance: 0,
      duration: '00:00:00',
      rule: [Object],
      device: [Object],
      diagnostic: [Object],
      driver: 'UnknownDriverId',
      version: '00000000000061bb',
      id: 'apk5czda9o06cwRzkSl4_dQ'
    }
  ],
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: 0
}
```

I am flattening JSON API responses with npm_flat. It is producing this output.

```
var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                  json = json.result
                  var json2 = flatten([json], { maxDepth: 15 });
                  console.log("API Response ", json2);

{
  '0.0.activeFrom': '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
  '0.0.activeTo': '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
  '0.0.distance': 0,
  '0.0.duration': '00:00:00',
  '0.0.rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId',
  '0.0.device.id': 'b1',
  '0.0.diagnostic.id': 'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId',
  '0.0.driver': 'UnknownDriverId',
  '0.0.version': '00000000000061b9',
  '0.0.id': 'a30M9pPNZSEq7DgUdYrF8xw',
  '0.1.activeFrom': '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
  '0.1.activeTo': '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
  '0.1.distance': 0,
  '0.1.duration': '00:00:00',
  '0.1.rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId',
  '0.1.device.id': 'b1',
  '0.1.diagnostic.id': 'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId',
  '0.1.driver': 'UnknownDriverId',
  '0.1.version': '00000000000061bb',
  '0.1.id': 'apk5czda9o06cwRzkSl4_dQ'
}
```

I would like the output to be flattened within the {} brackets but keep them intact so they can be inserted as "rows" into BigQuery.

I'm also having a lot of trouble getting rid of the numbers(**0.0.**) leading my keys. I have tried lots of code from research but I lack the JS knowledge to make this happen. Any input or solutions are much appreciated.

Output desired:

```
{
  'activeFrom': '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
  'activeTo': '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
  'distance': 0,
  'duration': '00:00:00',
  'rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId',
  'device.id': 'b1',
  'diagnostic.id': 'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId',
  'driver': 'UnknownDriverId',
  'version': '00000000000061b9',
  'id': 'a30M9pPNZSEq7DgUdYrF8xw',
},
{
  'activeFrom': '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
  'activeTo': '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
  'distance': 0,
  'duration': '00:00:00',
  'rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId',
  'device.id': 'b1',
  'diagnostic.id': 'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId',
  'driver': 'UnknownDriverId',
  'version': '00000000000061bb',
  'id': 'apk5czda9o06cwRzkSl4_dQ'
}
```

Comment: Your question seems confusing. Why do you want to flattened the array of object when you want to use it as row input?  Simply loop the result array and use each object as a row input. Please correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I'm flattening the array to produce a JSON schema file to feed to my BigQuery table. I have successfully uploaded records to Bigquery but I'm having an issue with the REPEATED columns (children of parent columns). Some of the unique keys can be value and other responses with the same key contain nested objects which is causing an issue inserting the data. I figured if I could flatten it all out, it would solve my problems.

Comment: Do you know the depth / complexity of the objects within the JSON? As in, could you have diagnostic.moredata.something? Or is it only one deep?

Comment: Some of the responses are nested 7 or 8 deep. I'm willing to have the column be a.b.c.d.e.f.... if needed just to start getting some data into the table.

Comment: @Bryan excuse my ignorance but would you mind giving me the gist on how to use that code with my example. I've been trying to make it work but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let totalResult = []

function formatter(obj) {
    let tempResult = {};
    function format(obj, position) {
        for(let key in obj) {
            let val = obj[key];
            let newKey = (position ? position + "." + key : key);
            if(val && typeof val === "object") {
                format(val, newKey);
            } else {
                tempResult[newKey] = val;
            }
        }
    };
    format(obj);
    return tempResult;
}

// your example data has no name. Let's pretend it's called "testData"
for (let i = 0; i < testData.result.length; i++) {
    totalResult.push(formatter(testData.result[i]));
}

// totalResult now contains your formatted data
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked as expected! One issue. It seems to add quotes the the .id keys? [
  {
    activeFrom: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
    activeTo: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
    distance: 0,
    duration: '00:00:00',
    'rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId',
    'device.id': 'b1',
    'diagnostic.id': 'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId',
    driver: 'UnknownDriverId',
    version: '00000000000061b9',
    id: 'a30M9pPNZSEq7DgUdYrF8xw'
  }

Comment: I should add that this displays correctly with no quotes in the browser but when run in the shell with node, the .id column have quotes added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` and then using `Object.keys` you can rename keys:

```
data.forEach((o, i) => {
    Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {
        o[`0.${i}.${k}`] = o[k];
        delete o[k];
    });
});
```

An example:

```js
let data = [
    {
      activeFrom: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
      activeTo: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
      distance: 0,
      duration: '00:00:00',
      rule: [Object],
      device: [Object],
      diagnostic: [Object],
      driver: 'UnknownDriverId',
      version: '00000000000061b9',
      id: 'a30M9pPNZSEq7DgUdYrF8xw'
    },
    {
      activeFrom: '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
      activeTo: '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
      distance: 0,
      duration: '00:00:00',
      rule: [Object],
      device: [Object],
      diagnostic: [Object],
      driver: 'UnknownDriverId',
      version: '00000000000061bb',
      id: 'apk5czda9o06cwRzkSl4_dQ'
    }
  ];

data.forEach((o, i) => {
    Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {
        o[`0.${i}.${k}`] = o[k];
        delete o[k];
    });
});
console.log(data);
```

**UPDATE:**

You can achieve desired result using `map` function:

```
const result = data.map(({ rule, device, diagnostic, ...rest})=>(
    { 'rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId', 
      'device.id': 'b1', 'diagnostic.id': 
      'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId', ...rest }));
```

An example:

```js
let data = [
    {
      activeFrom: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
      activeTo: '2018-02-15T16:02:20.003Z',
      distance: 0,
      duration: '00:00:00',
      rule: [Object],
      device: [Object],
      diagnostic: [Object],
      driver: 'UnknownDriverId',
      version: '00000000000061b9',
      id: 'a30M9pPNZSEq7DgUdYrF8xw'
    },
    {
      activeFrom: '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
      activeTo: '2018-02-15T16:06:03.003Z',
      distance: 0,
      duration: '00:00:00',
      rule: [Object],
      device: [Object],
      diagnostic: [Object],
      driver: 'UnknownDriverId',
      version: '00000000000061bb',
      id: 'apk5czda9o06cwRzkSl4_dQ'
    }
  ];

const result = data.map(({ rule, device, diagnostic, ...rest})=>({ 'rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId'
    , 'device.id': 'b1', 'diagnostic.id': 'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId', ...rest }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove all characters leading the base key (activeFrom, activeTo). I appreciate the try though.

Comment: When running your code suggestion, all the keys are leading with 0.0 or 0.1. I'm looking to get rid of those leading numbers and periods. I mention this in the bottom my original question but may have been lost . I will edit the post. thanks. Also you suggestion does not flatten the rule, device and diagnostic key arrays.

Comment: The values for rule ,device and diagnostic are in the last section of code in my original post. In that example, they are
'rule.id': 'RuleUnauthorizedDeviceRemovalId',
  'device.id': 'b1',
  'diagnostic.id': 'DiagnosticDeviceHasBeenUnpluggedId',
@StepUp